# Resume Bullet Point Alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize, cv

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.80}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Adjust margins to 0.5in on all sides
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.0in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\large \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabular*}{7.0in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-6pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{7.5in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\large Name}  & Phone Number \\
address &  email \\
township, state  zip code& website\\
\end{tabular*}
\\

\vspace{0.1in}

\resheading{Education}
\begin{itemize}
\item
    \ressubheading{University}{address}{degree}{grad date}

\end{itemize}

\resheading{Personal Projects}
\begin{itemize}
\item
    \ressubheading{Project 1}{address}{extra line}{date}
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{}
        \resitem{}
    \end{itemize}
\item   
    \ressubheading{Project 2}{address}{extra line}{date}
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{}
        \resitem{}
    \end{itemize}
\item
    \ressubheading{Project 3}{address}{extra line}{date}
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{}
        \resitem{}
    \end{itemize}
\item   
    \ressubheading{Project 4}{address}{extra line}{date}
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{}
        \resitem{}
    \end{itemize}

\end{itemize}

\resheading{Skills}

\begin{description}
\item[Languages:]


\item[Miscellaneous:]

\end{description}

\resheading{Open Source Projects}



\end{document}
```

Using a template I found online originally by David Grant.

I'm trying to align the bullet point with each project title in the Personal Project section and the Education section while also removing the "extra line" written under the project title. When I manually remove the extra line beneath the project title the space still stays there and the dashes looks unaligned. I would also like to remove the address and date that is aligned on the right side in the projects section. How would I go about doing all this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can align the bullets and the University entry (etc.) with `tabular`[t]` instead of tabular*

Comment: Please consider the usage of the `geometry` package that simplies changing page parameters -- using `\addtolength{...}` of the standard layout lengths is error-prone! ... and welcome to TeX.SX of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first starter, aligning the entries with the bullet and removing the `address` and `date` fields for the `project` entries.

I did not address the issues of manipulating the page geometry parameters.

The `alignment` of the entry an the bullet provided by `\item` can be done with `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{...}` -- the `[t]` parameter indicates `top` alignment, contrary to the standard `center` alignment when omitted!

The `address` and `date` fields can just be left empty in the relevant calls -- if more occurences of `\ressubheading` should be changed, it is better to use a different command rather.

The spacing below the gray headings are not caused by the gray headings -- it is the cause of the `\topsep` value from `itemize` -- the vertical spacing before **and** after an `enumerate` or `itemize` environment. 
The value is the same for top and bottom! Using `enumitem` package it can be changed to any value with, say, `\setlist[itemize]{topsep=6pt}`.

---

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.80}
\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Adjust margins to 0.5in on all sides
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.0in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{%
  {\large \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}%
}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \\
\end{tabularx}\vspace{-6pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{enumitem}% For \setlist...
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=6pt}% Change for all levels of itemize!
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular*}{7.5in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
\textbf{\large Name}  & Phone Number \\
address &  email \\
township, state  zip code& website\\
\end{tabular*}
\\

\vspace{0.1in}

\resheading{Education}
\begin{itemize}
\item  \ressubheading{University}{address}{degree}{grad date}
\end{itemize}

\resheading{Personal Projects}
\begin{itemize}
\item
    \ressubheading{Project 1}{}{extra line}{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{}
        \resitem{}
    \end{itemize}
\item   
    \ressubheading{Project 2}{}{extra line}{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{}
        \resitem{}
    \end{itemize}
\item
    \ressubheading{Project 3}{}{extra line}{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{}
        \resitem{}
    \end{itemize}
\item   
    \ressubheading{Project 4}{}{extra line}{}
    \begin{itemize}
        \resitem{}
        \resitem{}
    \end{itemize}

\end{itemize}

\resheading{Skills}

\begin{description}
\item[Languages:]


\item[Miscellaneous:]

\end{description}

\resheading{Open Source Projects}



\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** Some cleaner version

- Switched over to `geometry` package
- Using `X` column types
- Added some length parameters for fine control of spacings above and after the sub headings
- Using a `tcolorbox` environment for the gray headings

The bunch of warnings about overfull boxes has vanished now

---

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[lmargin=0.5in,rmargin=0.5in,tmargin=0.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Defining a right aligned stretchable R - columntype
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

% Defining colour(s)
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.80}

% Geometry and length settings
\parindent=0em

\newlength{\ressubheadingbeforeskip}
\setlength{\ressubheadingbeforeskip}{0pt}
\newlength{\ressubheadingafterskip}
\setlength{\ressubheadingafterskip}{-6pt}

\newlength{\projectheadingbeforeskip}
\setlength{\projectheadingbeforeskip}{0pt}
\newlength{\projectheadingafterskip}
\setlength{\projectheadingafterskip}{-6pt}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}


\newcommand{\resheading}[2][]{%
  \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,
    boxrule=0pt,
    left=\tabcolsep,
    boxsep=0pt,
    sharp corners,
    colback=mygrey,
    fontupper=\bfseries\large,
    nobeforeafter,
    after={\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}},
    #1%
    ]
    #2\vphantom{p\^{E}}%
  \end{tcolorbox}%
}

\newcommand{\ressubheading}[4]{%
  \vspace{\ressubheadingbeforeskip}%  
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{lR}
    \textbf{#1} & #2 \tabularnewline
    \textit{#3} & \textit{#4} \tabularnewline
  \end{tabularx}%
  \vspace{\ressubheadingafterskip}
}

\newcommand{\projectsubheading}[1]{%
  \vspace{\projectheadingbeforeskip}%  
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}[t]{lR}
    \textbf{#1} & 
  \end{tabularx}%
  \vspace{\projectheadingafterskip}%    
}

% -----------------------------------------------------------

% Some possible changes to the settings of itemize
\setlist[itemize,1]{itemsep=5pt}% 1st level
\setlist[itemize,2]{topsep=5pt}% 2nd level

% Empty page
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lR}
  \textbf{\large Name}  & Phone Number \\
address &  email \\
township, state  zip code& website\\
\end{tabularx}%

\medskip

\resheading{Education}
\begin{itemize}
\item  \ressubheading{University}{address}{degree}{grad date}
\end{itemize}

\resheading{Personal Projects}
\begin{itemize}
\item   \projectsubheading{Project 1}
  \begin{itemize}
    \resitem{}
    \resitem{}
  \end{itemize}
\item  \projectsubheading{Project 2}
  \begin{itemize}
    \resitem{}
    \resitem{}
  \end{itemize}
\item \projectsubheading{Project 3}
  \begin{itemize}
    \resitem{}
    \resitem{}
  \end{itemize}
\item  \projectsubheading{Project 4}
  \begin{itemize}
    \resitem{}
    \resitem{}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\resheading{Skills}

\begin{description}
\item[Languages:]
\item[Miscellaneous:]
\end{description}

\resheading[colback=white!40!yellow,boxrule=2pt]{Open Source Projects}
\end{document}
```

See the optional argument of `\resheading` how settings of the box can be changed.

Remove the `showframe` option to get rid off the frame -- it's there just for showing that the boundaries are correct.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to delete the "extra line" under the project title by changing \resubheading or by using the geometry package? I can delete the extra line but then the dashes underneath will be spaced away from the project title.

Comment: I try tomorrow, ok?

Comment: @ResumeUser: See the update please

Comment: Flawless work. Not only did you give me exactly what I needed but you also made it easy for me to edit this template later! I really appreciate this.

Comment: @ResumeUser: Great that it works ;-) By the way: The original template (apart from some LaTeX issues) is one of the better resume examples (from a typographical point of view) -- there are really bad ones